# Upload waypoints to OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, point, gpx, maps.me

I want to upload waypoints recorded in the Maps.me App onto openstreetmap.org for further editing.

Already tried:

- Export from Maps.me to `.kml` then conversion to `.gpx` with QGIS (second
  try with geotracker app)
- Then I added a fake trackpoint (because I had only recorded waypoints in maps.me) according to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Upload_Waypoints.
  Then the `.gpx` upload to OSM seemed to work but only the fake trackpoint was loaded.

What else can I do?